# Making a sound file with varying playback speed in Java

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I have managed to play a sound file with a different speed using answers from here, but I need to be able to adjust the speed as it plays. There's two methods I've thought of using. The first is to split the audio file into short clips and play each one after the last ends. I haven't tried that yet, but it seems like it could easily end with the file playing over itself or having short gaps.

The other method is to take the original file as a stream and then make a stream using that that speeds it up or slows it down as needed. This seems like it would work well, but in order to construct an AudioInputStream, I either need an InptutStream of known length, which is impossible to figure out ahead of time, or a TargetDataLine, which is an interface that has way more methods than I'd care to implement.

Is there a better way of doing this? Also, why does AudioInputStream need to know the length of the stream?

Alternately, is there an external library I could use?

Comment: Just to clarify: do you need the audio to sound naturally? I.e. without Mickey Mouse effect?

Comment: I'm not sure what that means. It should be higher-pitched when sped up and lower-pitched when sped down.

Comment: Create an `AudioInputStream` that either drops samples or adds zero samples. Make sure your (dropped/added) samples match the used `AudioFormat`. Regarding length: you can simply set the audio length to `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED`.

Comment: You need to linearly interpolate samples, but `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED` was the answer I needed. Can you add this as an answer so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are simply playing back an audio file (e.g., a .wav) and are okay with the pitch of the sound being shifted, a simple possibility is to read the data from an `AudioInputStream`, translate to PCM, interpolate though that data at the desired rate, translate back to bytes an ship out via a `SourceDataLine`.

To speed up or slow down in real time, loosely couple inputs to the variable holding the increment being used to progress through the incoming frames. To minimize discontinuities, you can smooth out the transitions from one pitch to another over a given number of frames.

This is done to achieve real-time frequency changes in the open source library [AudioCue](https://github.com/philfrei/AudioCue), on github. Smoothing there between frequency changes is set to occur over 1028 frames (approx 1/40th of a second). But quicker changes are certainly possible. The sound data in that library is take from an internal float array of PCM values. But a good example of code needed to read the data as a line rather than a fixed array can be seen in the first code example in the [Sound Trail, Using File Filters and Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html). You might be wanting to use an `InputStream` as the argument for the `AudioInputStream`. At the point in the example where it says "Here, do something useful.." you would convert to PCM and then cursor through the resulting PCM with the desired frequency rate, using linear interpolation, and then repackage and send out via a `SourceDataLine`.

If you wish to preserve pitch (time stretch or compress only) then this starts to require more heavy duty DSP. [This thread at the StackExchange Digital Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/40101/audio-time-stretching-without-pitch-shifting) site has some info on that. I've had some success with making granules with a *Hamming Window* to aid cross-fading between them, but some of the other solutions were over my head (and I haven't been back to this problem in a long while). But it was possible to change the spacing of the granules in real time, if I remember correctly. Didn't sound as good as the Audacity tool's algorithm, though, but that's probably more on me than not. I'm pretty much self-taught and experimenting, not working in the field professionally.

Answer (score 1):

(I believe [Phil's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58124141/942774) answer will get you going nicely. I'm just posting this to add my two cents about resampling.)

**Short answer:** Create an `AudioInputStream` that either drops samples or adds zero samples. As length you can set `AudioSystem.NOT_SPECIFIED`.

**Long answer:** If you add zero samples, you might want to *interpolate*, but not linearly. The reason you have to interpolate for upsampling is [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing), which you might want to avoid. You do so, by applying a [lowpass filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-pass_filter). The reason for this is simple. The [Nyquist-Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) states that when a signal is sampled at `X Hz`, you can only unambiguously represent frequencies up to `X/2 Hz`. When you upsample, you *increase* the sample frequency, so in theory you can represent a larger frequency range. Indeed, when simply adding zeros you see some energy in those additional frequency ranges—which shouldn't be there, because you have no information about it. So you need to "cut them off" using a low pass filter. More about upsampling can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upsampling#Upsampling_by_an_integer_factor).

Long story short, there is a proper way to do it. You seem to be OK with distortions, so doing it the *right way* may not be necessary, but a waste of time.

Shameless plug: If you nevertheless want to do it *somewhat right*, you might find the [Resample](https://github.com/hendriks73/jipes/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tagtraum/jipes/math/MultirateFilters.java#L261) class of [jipes](http://www.tagtraum.com/jipes/) useful. It's not a universal resampler, i.e., it only supports a limited number of factors, like `2`, `4`, ..., but it may prove useful for you.

```
import com.tagtraum.jipes.math.MultirateFilters.Resampler;

[...]

float[] original = ... ; // original signal as float

Resampler downsampler2 = new MultirateFilters.Resampler(1, 2);
float[] downsampled = downsampler2.map(original);

Resampler upsampler2 = new MultirateFilters.Resampler(2, 1);
float[] upsampled = upsampler2.map(original);
```

If you want to [time-scale modification (TSM)](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/sasp/Time_Scale_Modification.html), i.e., changing the tempo without changing the frequencies, you might want to use [Rubberband for Java](https://github.com/JorenSix/RubberBandJNI).